# Vagrant mount folder twice in df command

Tags: vagrant

here's df result:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/precise64-root   78G  3.7G   70G   6% /
udev                        172M  4.0K  172M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        73M  296K   73M   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        182M     0  182M   0% /run/shm
cgroup                      182M     0  182M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   228M   53M  164M  25% /boot
vagrant                     233G   82G  152G  35% /vagrant
vagrant                     233G   82G  152G  35% /vagrant
srv_website                 233G   82G  152G  35% /srv/website
srv_website                 233G   82G  152G  35% /srv/website
```

key mount info :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "vagrant_data" ,"/srv/website"
```

**It's odd that /vagrant is mounted and mount twice, so as /srv/website**

```
vagrant                     233G   82G  152G  35% /vagrant
vagrant                     233G   82G  152G  35% /vagrant
srv_website                 233G   82G  152G  35% /srv/website
srv_website                 233G   82G  152G  35% /srv/website
```

Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  #config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.box = "afterdocker"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  #config.vm.network "public_network"
  #config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
  # Iterating the loop for three times
    (1..2).each do |i|
        # Defining VM properties
        config.vm.define "nvm#{i}" do |node|
            # Specifying the provider as VirtualBox and naming the VM's
            config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |node|
                # The VM will be named as nvm{i}
                node.name = "nvm#{i}"
            end
        end
    end

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "vagrant_data" ,"/srv/website"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

My env:

- OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
- VirtualBox 5.0.26
- vbox: hashicorp/precise64 ubuntu 12.04

I recently install plugin:
`vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: Did you notice that Vagrant syncs a default folder "/vagrant" maybe you are synced twice.
You can disabled this behaviour https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#disabling

Comment: does it happen on all boxes or only 1 of them ?

Comment: It looks like that applies for all boxes.

Comment: vagrant                     233G   93G  141G  40% /vagrant
vagrant                     233G   93G  141G  40% /vagrant after disable  sync , still odd : folder /vagrant mount twice